# Converting text to rows in a huge dataset

Tags: microsoft-excel

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rmgk5EyOR11zSIc5H0dNzLULpeim0G3T/view?usp=sharing

I've got a list of more than 1000 suppliers that are in the same format as in sheet 1, from an export.

I need to narrow this down to around 200 - I've got another spreadsheet with this list.
Sheet 2 shows the result I am trying to get. All I need to keep from sheet 1 is the supplier name and the info that is in C10 and D10 (from the top supplier)

I've played around with text to columns, transposing etc but had no luck, seems a rather difficult task - I think it may be easier if I could somehow get the text into rows besides the supplier code and supplier name, and then use v-lookup to remove the ones I don't need?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please edit your post and add a sample of the data as document from an external source can be removed or changed over time,

Comment: Adding an some example data would help, but a quick look from what i understand of your request. Do a VLOOKUP on Sheet1 against the list on Sheet2 (The ones you want to keep). Filter for the errors, delete those rows. You should now only have the suppliers you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you can try a formula solution like this:

[image]

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$12,FALSE)),0,1,1,1)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$12,FALSE)),9,1,1,1)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$12,FALSE)),9,2,1,1)
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$12,FALSE)),9,3,1,1)
```

On sheet 2 these formula go in B1, C1, D1 and E1 from top to bottom, the match formula returns the row of the serial number then the offset function returns the required data (it requires the format to be standard throughout)

Justin